# How to replace numbers with an empty char

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to replace phone number in string on `\n` new line.
My string: `Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366`

I tried this:

```
var str = 'Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366'
var regex = /[0-9]/g;
var rec = str.trim().replace(regex, '\n').split(','); //Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,
```

Number replace on `\n` but after using e-mail extra comma is in the string need to remove it.

Finally my string should look like this:

```
Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com\n
```

Comment: you can simply add a comma `,` before the numbers in the regex pattern, (e.g):- `/,\d+/`.

Comment: `str.trim().replace(regex, '\n').split(',').slice(0,2).join(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var str = 'Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366';
var regex = /,[0-9]+/g;
str.replace(regex, '\n');
```

The snippet above may output what you want, i.e. `Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com\n`

Comment: It should be `/,[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Yeah,  the `/,[0-9]+$/` in this context is more accurate. Thanks! @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to that, and this is so easy, so try this simple answer:-

```
var str = 'Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366';
var splitted = str.split(",");      //split them by comma
splitted.pop();                     //removes the last element
var rec = splitted.join() + '\n';   //join them
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex to select the complete phone number and also the preceding comma. Your current regex selects each digit and replaces each one with an "\n", resulting in a lot of "\n" in the result. Also the regex does not match the comma.

Use the following regex:

```
var str = 'Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366'
var regex = /,[0-9]+$/; 
// it replaces all consecutive digits with the condition at least one digit exists (the "[0-9]+" part) 
// placed at the end of the string (the "$" part) 
// and also the digits must be preceded by a comma (the "," part in the beginning); 
// also no need for global flag (/g) because of the $ symbol (the end of the string) which can be matched only once
var rec = str.trim().replace(regex, '\n'); //the result will be this string: Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com\n
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Jhony Jhons,jhon@gmail.com,380967574366";
var result = str.replace(/,\d+/g,'\\n');
console.log(result)
```